# How does the following queueMicrotask polyfill fallback to using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise, event-loop

Consider the following [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask#When_queueMicrotask_isnt_available) for [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask).

```js
if (typeof window.queueMicrotask !== "function") {
  window.queueMicrotask = function (callback) {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(callback)
      .catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }));
  };
}
```

The description on MDN states.

> It creates a microtask by using a promise that resolves immediately, falling back to using a timeout if the promise can't be created.

The [queue-microtask](https://github.com/feross/queue-microtask) library also uses the same polyfill. Here's what its documentation says.

> - Optimal performance in all modern environments.
>
>   - Use `queueMicrotask` in modern environments (optimal)
>   - Fallback to `Promise.resolve().then(fn)` in Node.js 10 and earlier, and old browsers (optimal)
>   - Fallback to `setTimeout` in JS environments without Promise (slow)

This raises more questions than answers.

- Wouldn't `Promise` be `undefined` in JS environments without promises?
- Why are we throwing the error instead of calling `callback` within `setTimeout`?
- Why are we using a separate `catch` instead of passing the error handler to `then`?
- How does this polyfill fallback to using `setTimeout` when “the promise can't be created”?
- When would the promise not be created?

I would have expected the polyfill to be implemented as follows.

```js
if (typeof window.queueMicrotask !== "function") {
  window.queueMicrotask = callback =>
    typeof Promise === "function" && typeof Promise.resolve === "function"
      ? Promise.resolve().then(callback)
      : setTimeout(callback, 0);
}
```

What's the reason why it's not implemented so?

**Edit:** I was going through the commit history of the queue-microtask library and I found [this commit](https://github.com/feross/queue-microtask/commit/3a34dc827c2915505c0286c70800284659a20898).

```js
@@ -1,9 +1,8 @@
-let resolvedPromise
+let promise

 module.exports = typeof queueMicrotask === 'function'
   ? queueMicrotask
-  : (typeof Promise === 'function' ? (resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve()) : false)
-    ? cb => resolvedPromise
-      .then(cb)
-      .catch(err => setTimeout(() => { throw err }, 0))
-    : cb => setTimeout(cb, 0)
+  // reuse resolved promise, and allocate it lazily
+  : cb => (promise || (promise = Promise.resolve()))
+    .then(cb)
+    .catch(err => setTimeout(() => { throw err }, 0))
```

So, it seems as though this library did indeed fallback to using `cb => setTimeout(cb, 0)`. However, this was later removed. It might have been a mistake which went unnoticed. As for the MDN article, they might have just copied the snippet blindly from this library.

Comment: why would you think it would do that? oh, wait, yes, I see, you're right

Comment: It seems both the MDN example and that library just assume Promise exists (a fair assumption given the desire to kill IE once and for all)

Comment: In that case, it would never fallback to using `setTimeout`. That's false advertising.

Comment: You are correct, it won't - you should add an issue to that library to mention that falsehood :p

Comment: gave you a for your comment on github

Comment: `As for the MDN article, they might have just copied the snippet blindly from this library.` the MDN "polyfill" pre-dates the creation of this library by one day - if anything this library copied the MDN polyfill (and fixed it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are entirely right in your main points, this polyfill won't work if there is no Promise in the environment, and I did edit the MDN article to now call it a "monkey-patch" as it is what it is and I removed the reference to "fallback" as there isn't.

To answer your questions:

- Yes `Promise` would be undefined and thus the polyfill would just throw:

```js
delete window.queueMicrotask;
delete window.Promise;

if (typeof window.queueMicrotask !== "function") {
  window.queueMicrotask = function (callback) {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(callback)
      .catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }));
  };
}

queueMicrotask( () => console.log('hello') );
```

But this "shim" is apparently [only aimed at "modern engines"](https://github.com/feross/queue-microtask#fast-tiny-queuemicrotask-shim-for-modern-engines).

- The MDN editor that [did introduce that exception throwing here](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask$revision/1564360) did so because the specs ask that [`queueMicroTask` reports any exception](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#microtask-queuing:report-the-exception) that would be thrown during `callback` execution. The Promise chain would "*swallow*" this exception (it wouldn't get thrown globally), so to get out of this Promise chain, we have to call `setTimeout` from inside the `.catch()` handler.
- Handling from the second parameter of `then` wouldn't handle Exceptions thrown from the callback execution, which is just what we want to do here.
- It doesn't fallback to anything else than `Promise`, as we shown in the previous bullets it would just throw in case `Promise` is not defined, and the `setTimeout` is only used to throw the Exception out of the Promise chain.
- The Promise would not be created by `Promise.resolve()` when that function would be something else than a correct Promise implementation. And if it's the case, there is like no chance it returns a catchable object either ;) But As you may have caught now, only the explanation text was completely mislead+ing.

---

Now, a note about your monkey-patch which still might be improvable a little bit:

- This editor was actually correct that the [error should be reported](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#microtask-queuing:report-the-exception), the `catch` + `setTimeout` should be there.
- `queueMicrotask` should throw if *callback* is not *Callable*.
- Nitpick, but the callback passed to  `.then()` will be called with one argument `undefined`, `queueMicrotask` calls its callback without any argument.
- Nitpick again, checking every time if Promise is available doesn't sound great, either Promise is defined from the beginning, either you'll use a polyfill you don't know how they managed the asynchronicity.
- More importantly (?) you may want to add support for more environments.

---

The [*queue a microtask*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-microtask) algorithm was already part of the Web standards before Promises make their way to browsers: `MutationObserver` [queues microtasks too](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#queue-a-mutation-observer-compound-microtask), and it was supported in IE11 (unlike Promises).

```js
function queueMutationObserverMicrotask( callback ) {
  var observer = new MutationObserver( function() {
    callback();
    observer.disconnect();
  } );
  var target = document.createElement( 'div' );
  observer.observe( target, { attributes: true } );
  target.setAttribute( 'data-foo', '' );
}

Promise.resolve().then( () => console.log( 'Promise 1' ) );
queueMutationObserverMicrotask( () => console.log('from mutation') );
Promise.resolve().then( () => console.log( 'Promise 2' ) );
```

In node.js < 0.11, `process.nextTick()` was the closest to what microtasks are, so you may want to add it too (it's short enough).

```
if( typeof process === "object" && typeof process.nextTick === "function" ) {
  process.nextTick( callback );
}
```

So all in all, our improved polyfill would look like

```js
(function() {
'use strict';

// lazy get globalThis, there might be better ways
const globalObj = typeof globalThis === "object" ? globalThis :
  typeof global === "object" ? global :
  typeof window === "object" ? window :
  typeof self === 'object' ? self :
  Function('return this')();

if (typeof queueMicrotask !== "function") {

  const checkIsCallable = (callback) => {
    if( typeof callback !== 'function' ) {
      throw new TypeError( "Failed to execute 'queueMicrotask': the callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function" );
    }  
  };

  if( typeof Promise === "function" && typeof Promise.resolve === "function" ) {
    globalObj.queueMicrotask = (callback) => {
      checkIsCallable( callback );
      Promise.resolve()
        .then( () => callback() ) // call with no arguments
        // if any error occurs during callback execution,
        // throw it back to globalObj (using setTimeout to get out of Promise chain)
        .catch( (err) => setTimeout( () => { throw err; } ) );
   };
  }
  else if( typeof MutationObserver === 'function' ) {
    globalObj.queueMicrotask = (callback) => {
      checkIsCallable( callback );
      const observer = new MutationObserver( function() {
        callback();
        observer.disconnect();
      } );
      const target = document.createElement( 'div' );
      observer.observe( target, { attributes: true } );
      target.setAttribute( 'data-foo', '');
    };
  }
  else if( typeof process === "object" && typeof process.nextTick === "function" ) {
    globalObj.queueMicrotask = (callback) => {
      checkIsCallable( callback );
      process.nextTick( callback );
    };
  }
  else {
    globalObj.queueMicrotask = (callback) => {
      checkIsCallable( callback );
      setTimeout( callback, 0 );
    }
  }
}
})();

queueMicrotask( () => console.log( 'microtask' ) );
console.log( 'sync' );
```

Comment: This is one of the best explained answers, I'd point, we can even fallback to `setTimeout` in case someone is fine with queuing it to the Macrotask queue if the Microtask queue is unavailable in the current env.

Comment: @Kaiido your knowledge about JS and browser amazes me every time i read your answers on SO ;)